# Direction of calculating multiple Arrays stored values and displaying them

Tags: java

I am trying to write up a program that accepts user input and stores it in arrays Its really complex, I looked around a bit and read the book. I just cannot figure out how to do this. Heres the prompt I have

> Modify lab 20 to add copy constructors to petRecord, catRecord, dogRecord and birdRecord.  Use your main file from HW 6 as a starting point for main.  When having the user fill in information for each pet, also include having them choose from cat, dog or bird by entering 1, 2 or 3 on the keyboard.  Store the appropriate object into each array slot (catRecord, dogRecord or birdRecord).  When comparing to see if two pets are the same be sure to check if they are the same type of animal as well as matching data, and ensure that numFeathers matches for birds and hasLongHair matches for cats/dogs.
>
> In addition to the array, have main create an additional pet with information given by the user (as for the five in the array), then copy it to a new object using its’ copy constructor.  Test that this worked by showing that they are equal (the same way you tested if any pets in the array were equal to each other).

In main is where I am having trouble calculating all weights and age of the animals. I have no idea what to do, just some direction is needed.

```
public class petRecordMain 
{
     public static void main(String[] args) 
    {  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        PetRecord[] petArray = new PetRecord[6];
        DogRecord[] dogArray = new DogRecord[6];
        CatRecord[] catArray = new CatRecord[6];
        BirdRecord[] birdArray = new BirdRecord[6];
        double averageWeight = 0;
        double averageAge = 0;
        int whichPet = 0; 
        for(int i = 0; i < petArray.length; i++)
       {
           petArray[i] = new PetRecord();
           dogArray[i] = new DogRecord();
           catArray[i] = new CatRecord();
           birdArray[i] = new BirdRecord();
       }
        
        
         for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
       {
            System.out.println("Please choose, 1 for Cat, 2 for Dog, 3 for Bird: ");
            whichPet = in.nextInt();
            switch(whichPet)
            {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("Cat");
                     System.out.println("Enter the name of Pet "+ i + " :  ");//Asks user for input
                     catArray[i].setName(in.next());                   //For five animals, weight, age
                     System.out.println("Enter the weight of Pet "+ i + " : "); //add up then divide by all five weight
                     catArray[i].setWeight(in.nextInt());
                     System.out.println("Enter the age of Pet"+ i + " : ");
                     catArray[i].setAge(in.nextInt());
                    
                    break;
                    
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("Dog");
                        System.out.println("Enter the name of Pet "+ i + " :  ");//Asks user for input
                        dogArray[i].setName(in.next());                   //For five animals, weight, age
                        System.out.println("Enter the weight of Pet "+ i + " : "); //add up then divide by all five weight
                        dogArray[i].setWeight(in.nextInt());
                        System.out.println("Enter the age of Pet"+ i + " : ");
                        dogArray[i].setAge(in.nextInt());
                    
                    break;
                    
                case 3:
                    System.out.println("Bird");
                     System.out.println("Enter the name of Pet "+ i + " :  ");//Asks user for input
                     birdArray[i].setName(in.next());                   //For five animals, weight, age
                     System.out.println("Enter the weight of Pet "+ i + " : "); //add up then divide by all five weight
                     birdArray[i].setWeight(in.nextInt());
                     System.out.println("Enter the age of Pet"+ i + " : ");
                     birdArray[i].setAge(in.nextInt());
                    
                    break;
                    
                    default :
                        System.out.println("Invalid input, try again.");
                    
            }
            
       }
```

Down below the code is a little messy. I have a `for` loop which I think I can use to calculate all the weights and ages, but this is where I am now stuck.

```
     for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
   {
        averageWeight += petArray.getWeight[i]; //How would I calculate all weight?
        //How would I caculate all ages?
        System.out.println("");
        
     
   }
   /*
    averageWeight = (petOne.getWeight()+petTwo.getWeight()+petThree.getWeight()+petFour.getWeight()+petFive.getWeight()) /5;
    averageAge = (petOne.getAge()+petTwo.getAge()+petThree.getAge()+petFour.getAge()+petFive.getAge()) /5;
    
    System.out.println("The average weight of all dogs is: "+averageWeight+" Pounds");
    System.out.println("The average age of all dogs is: "+averageAge+" years old"); 
    System.out.println("");
    
    if(petOne.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(petTwo.getName()) && petThree.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(petFour.getName()) && petFour.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(petFive.getName()) )
    {
            System.out.println("All five dogs have the same name.");
    }
    else if(petOne.getWeight() == petTwo.getWeight() && petThree.getWeight() == petFour.getWeight() && petFour.getName() == petFive.getName())
    {
        System.out.println("All five dogs have the same weight");
    }
    else if(petOne.getAge() == petTwo.getAge() && petThree.getAge() == petFour.getAge() && petFour.getAge() == petFive.getAge())
    {
        System.out.println("All five dogs are the same age.");
    }
    //Below check if any pets are the same
    //1
     if(petOne.toString().equals(petTwo.toString()))
    {
        System.out.println(petOne.toString()+" and "+petTwo.toString()+" are the same");
    }
    else if(petOne.toString().equals(petThree.toString()))
    {
        System.out.println(petOne.toString()+" and "+petThree.toString()+" are the same");
    }
    else if(petOne.toString().equals(petFour.toString()))
    {
        System.out.println(petOne.toString()+" and "+petFour.toString()+ "are the same");
    }
    else if(petOne.toString().equals(petFive.toString()))
    {
        System.out.println(petOne.toString()+" and "+petFive.toString()+" are the same");
    }
    //2
        if(petTwo.toString().equals(petOne.toString()))
    {
        System.out.println(petTwo.toString()+" and "+petOne.toString()+" are the sae");
    }
    else if(petTwo.toString().equals(petThree.toString()))
    {
        System.out.println(petTwo.toString()+" and "+petThree.toString()+" are the same");
    }
    else if(petTwo.toString().equals(petFour.toString()))
    {
        System.out.println(petTwo.toString()+" and "+petFour.toString()+" are the same");
    }
    else if(petTwo.toString().equals(petFive.toString()))
    {
        System.out.println(petTwo.toString()+" and "+petFive.toString()+" are the same");
    }
    //3
        if(petThree.toString().equals(petOne.toString()))
    {
        System.out.println(petThree.toString()+" and "+petOne.toString()+" are the same");
    }
     else if(petThree.toString().equals(petTwo.toString()))
    {
        System.out.println(petThree.toString()+" and "+petTwo.toString()+" are the same");
    }
    else if(petThree.toString().equals(petFour.toString()))
    {
        System.out.println(petThree.toString()+" and "+petFour.toString()+" are the same");
    }
    else if(petThree.toString().equals(petFive.toString()))
    {
        System.out.println(petThree.toString()+" and "+petFive.toString()+" are the same");
    }
    //4
        if(petFour.toString().equals(petOne.toString()))
    {
        System.out.println(petFour.toString()+" and "+petOne.toString()+" are the same");
    }
    else if(petFour.toString().equals(petTwo.toString()))
    {
        System.out.println(petFour.toString()+" and "+petTwo.toString()+" are the same");
    }
    else if(petFour.toString().equals(petThree.toString()))
    {
        System.out.println(petFour.toString()+" and "+petThree.toString()+" are the same");
    }
    else if(petFour.toString().equals(petFive.toString()))
    {
        System.out.println(petFour.toString()+" and "+petFour.toString()+" are the same");
    }
    //5
        if(petFive.toString().equals(petOne.toString()))
    {
        System.out.println(petFive.toString()+" and "+petOne.toString()+" are the same");
    }
    else if(petFive.toString().equals(petTwo.toString()))
    {
        System.out.println(petFive.toString()+" and "+petTwo.toString()+" are the same");
    }
    else if(petFive.toString().equals(petThree.toString()))
    {
        System.out.println(petFive.toString()+" and "+petThree.toString()+" are the same");
    }
    else if(petFive.toString().equals(petFour.toString()))
    {
        System.out.println(petFive.toString()+" and "+petFour.toString()+" are the same");
    }
    //Below caculates which pet is the youngest
    
        if(petOne.getAge() < petTwo.getAge() && petOne.getAge() < petThree.getAge() && petOne.getAge() < petFour.getAge() && petOne.getAge() < petFive.getAge())
    {
        System.out.println(petOne.getName()+" is the youngest pet.");
    }
    else if(petTwo.getAge() < petOne.getAge() && petTwo.getAge() < petThree.getAge() && petTwo.getAge() < petFour.getAge() && petTwo.getAge() < petFive.getAge())
    {
        System.out.println(petTwo.getName()+" is the youngest pet.");
    }
    else if(petThree.getAge() < petOne.getAge() && petThree.getAge() < petTwo.getAge() && petThree.getAge() < petFour.getAge() && petThree.getAge() < petFive.getAge())
    {
        System.out.println(petThree.getName()+" is the youngest pet.");
    }
    else if(petFour.getAge() < petOne.getAge() && petFour.getAge() < petTwo.getAge() && petFour.getAge() < petThree.getAge() && petFour.getAge() < petFive.getAge())
    {
        System.out.println(petFour.getName()+" is the youngest pet.");
    }
    else if(petFive.getAge() < petOne.getAge() && petFive.getAge() < petTwo.getAge() && petFive.getAge() < petThree.getAge() && petFive.getAge() < petFour.getAge())
    {
        System.out.println(petFive.getName()+" is the youngest pet.");
    }
    //Below caculates which pet is the oldest 
        if(petOne.getAge() > petTwo.getAge() && petOne.getAge() > petThree.getAge() && petOne.getAge() > petFour.getAge() && petOne.getAge() > petFive.getAge())
    {
        System.out.println(petOne.getName()+" is the oldest pet.");
    }
     else if(petTwo.getAge() > petOne.getAge() && petTwo.getAge() > petThree.getAge() && petTwo.getAge() > petFour.getAge() && petTwo.getAge() > petFive.getAge())
    {
        System.out.println(petTwo.getName()+" is the oldest pet.");
    }
     else if(petThree.getAge() > petOne.getAge() && petThree.getAge() > petTwo.getAge() && petThree.getAge() > petFour.getAge() && petThree.getAge() > petFive.getAge())
    {
        System.out.println(petThree.getName()+" is the oldest pet.");
    }
     else if(petFour.getAge() > petOne.getAge() && petFour.getAge() > petTwo.getAge() && petFour.getAge() > petThree.getAge() && petFour.getAge() > petFive.getAge())
    {
        System.out.println(petFour.getName()+" is the oldest pet.");
    }
     else if(petFive.getAge() > petOne.getAge() && petFive.getAge() > petTwo.getAge() && petFive.getAge() > petThree.getAge() && petFive.getAge() > petFour.getAge())
    {
        System.out.println(petFive.getName()+" is the oldest pet.");
    }
    //Below caculates which pet is the smallest
        if(petOne.getWeight() < petTwo.getWeight() && petOne.getWeight() < petThree.getWeight() && petOne.getWeight() < petFour.getWeight() && petOne.getWeight() < petFive.getWeight())
    {
        System.out.println(petOne.getName()+" is the smallest pet.");
    }
     else if(petTwo.getWeight() < petOne.getWeight() && petTwo.getWeight() < petThree.getWeight() && petTwo.getWeight() < petFour.getWeight() && petTwo.getWeight() < petFive.getWeight())
    {
        System.out.println(petTwo.getName()+" is the smallest pet.");
    }
     else if(petThree.getWeight() < petOne.getWeight() && petThree.getWeight() < petTwo.getWeight() && petThree.getWeight() < petFour.getWeight() && petThree.getAge() < petFive.getWeight())
    {
        System.out.println(petThree.getName()+" is the smallest pet.");
    }
     else if(petFour.getWeight() < petOne.getWeight() && petFour.getWeight() < petTwo.getWeight() && petFour.getWeight() < petThree.getWeight() && petFour.getWeight() < petFive.getWeight())
    {
        System.out.println(petFour.getName()+" is the smallest pet.");
    }
     else  if(petFive.getWeight() < petOne.getWeight() && petFive.getWeight() < petTwo.getWeight() && petFive.getWeight() < petThree.getWeight() && petFive.getWeight() < petFour.getWeight())
    {
        System.out.println(petFive.getName()+" is the smallest pet.");
    }
    //Below caculates to see which pet is the largest
        if(petOne.getWeight() > petTwo.getWeight() && petOne.getWeight() > petThree.getWeight() && petOne.getWeight() > petFour.getWeight() && petOne.getWeight() > petFive.getWeight())
    {
        System.out.println(petOne.getName()+" is the largest pet.");
    }
     else if(petTwo.getWeight() > petOne.getWeight() && petTwo.getWeight() > petThree.getWeight() && petTwo.getWeight() > petFour.getWeight() && petTwo.getWeight() > petFive.getWeight())
    {
        System.out.println(petTwo.getName()+" is the largest pet.");
    }
     else if(petThree.getWeight() > petOne.getWeight() && petThree.getWeight() > petTwo.getWeight() && petThree.getWeight() > petFour.getWeight() && petThree.getAge() > petFive.getWeight())
    {
        System.out.println(petThree.getName()+" is the largest pet.");
    }
    else if(petFour.getWeight() > petOne.getWeight() && petFour.getWeight() > petTwo.getWeight() && petFour.getWeight() > petThree.getWeight() && petFour.getWeight() > petFive.getWeight())
    {
        System.out.println(petFour.getName()+" is the largest pet.");
    }
    else if(petFive.getWeight() > petOne.getWeight() && petFive.getWeight() > petTwo.getWeight() && petFive.getWeight() > petThree.getWeight() && petFive.getWeight() > petFour.getWeight())
    {
        System.out.println(petFive.getName()+" is the largest pet.");
    }
    
    
   */
```

Comment: Could you refine your question? At the moment it is quite verbose.
See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe CatRecord must be inheriting PetRecord, would have clarified this in a comment before answering but unfortunately, StackOverflow won't allow me to comment.Hence if the weight is stored in the PetRecord as all Pets have weight regardless of species and that would make sense. Something like this should work:

```
averageWeight += petArray[i].getWeight();
```

Also while initialising, write code on the lines of:

```
petarray[i] = new CatRecord();
```